# matplotlib legend display issue

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, matplotlib, apache-spark-sql

I'm getting two values from my dataframe .i.e. ('Passed',Failed'). Based on these values trying to build a pie chart. I like to display both values in legend even though the values are not present in my dataframe.
Dataframe values are 'passed','failed'

```
colors = ['green','red']

ax_3 = df_spark["Missing_records_check"].value_counts().sort_index(ascending=False).plt(
    kind='pie',
    y="Missing_records_check",
    figsize=(10, 10),
    legend=True,
    autopct='%1.1f%%',
    startangle=90,
    shadow=False,
    colors=['green','red'])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating a categorical variable will help.

```
from pandas.api.types import CategoricalDtype
colors = ['green','red']

labels=['Passed','Failed']

cat_type = CategoricalDtype(categories=labels, ordered=True)
df_spark["Missing_records_check"] = df_spark["Missing_records_check"].astype(cat_type)
ax_3 =df_spark["Missing_records_check"].value_counts().sort_index(ascending=True)\
.plot(kind='pie',y="Missing_records_check", figsize=(10, 10),legend=True,autopct='%1.1f%%',\
     startangle=90,shadow=False,colors=['green','red'])
```

Since you also want to remove the labels for non-existing categories, I will probably use a custom legend. I have also added a line to sort the color based on values.-

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.patches as mpatches

color= ['red' if l == 'Failed' else 'green' for l in df_spark['Missing_records_check']]

ax_3 =df_spark["Missing_records_check"].value_counts().sort_index(ascending=False)\
.plot(kind='pie',y="Missing_records_check", figsize=(10, 10),autopct='%1.1f%%',\
     startangle=90,shadow=False,colors=color, legend=True)

red_patch = mpatches.Patch(color='red', label='Failed')
green_patch = mpatches.Patch(color='green', label='Passed')
ax_3.legend(handles=[green_patch, red_patch])
```

Comment: Its works great but 2 different items pops up now 1. color is not fixed for each label. i.e. Label "Passed" should be always green and "Failed" should be always red, currently it is "Failed" is green. 2. if any of the two value has 0% is still getting displayed with a black in the middle of pie chart.Please let me know how to avoid this. Thanks in advance

Comment: @Jack, please see that I have used sort_index(ascending=True), this will actually work for the colors.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response. Legends are working absolutely fine but the pie chart values are not matching with the legends. For example: Pie value is Failed but legend shown for Passed.

Comment: Coloring is based on the pie chart values not based on the axis labels I have edited my original post as well. Sorry of the confusion.

Comment: @Jack I have added a line to sort the colors based on the values. This should work for you